# C# Azure DocumentDB Authorization Key Permissions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I was wondering if there's a way to ascertain the level of the Authorization Key used when connecting to Azure DocumentDB.

Mainly to prevent attempts at creating documents or modifying documents when a read-only Authorization key was supplied.

Something along the lines of

```
static async void LogIn(string url, string authKey)
{
    DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(url), authKey);
    if(?clientpermissions?== PermissionMode.Read)
    { Console.WriteLine("You are in read-only mode."); }
}
```

I see the user class has a permission object that can be accessed, but when purely using auth keys I'm a bit lost.

I had considered trying to create a document and seeing if there was an exception but I don't really like using failure as a conditional seems like bad practice.

The goal here is a sort of tool (I know a few already exist, this is more of an exercise for my skills) to manage the document databases. So along those lines say someone attempts to access the databases with a key they were given, they may or may not be given a rw key wherein they may also not know the permissions. Ideally a label or indicator could be shown to state their access level.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client is constructed with the authorization key and has no more information about it than you at that point. It's just a string.

You may be able to leverage the [DocumentClient.ReadPermissionAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readpermissionasync.aspx) method to get permissions of a resource. I have not tried this first hand, but may be good to explore.

However, you might as well try to read/write the original document you're after and catch the exception when applicable due to limited permissions. This is because you'd need to make a request anyway just to get the permissions.

I'm not privy to why you're doing what you're doing, however, I'd take a step back an ask yourself if you can ensure you'll have the right key for the read/write operation you'd like to do.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Kurifodo. The goal here is a sort of tool (I know a few already exist, this is more of an exercise for my skills) to manage the document databases.
So along those lines say someone attempts to access the databases with a key they were given, they may or may not be given a rw key wherein they may also not know the permissions. Ideally a label or indicator could be shown to state their access level.

Comment: I'd also like to mention that ReadPermissionAsync is aimed more at a user level not actually for the auth keys themselves.